# Angular 12 array empty in form group selected using reactive form

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular12

**.html File**

```
   <div  *ngFor="let analysis of analysisFormArray.controls; let i = index" [class.selected]="analysis === selectedAnalysis">
          <div  [formGroup]="analysis" (click)="onSelect(analysis)">
            <div class="d-flex">
            
              <div>
                <div class="mail-title" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-xs style="min-width: 120px;">
                  <span>{{analysis.value.analysisName}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="text-ellipsis">
                  <span class="text-muted">Analiz açıklaması</span>
                </div>
                <div class="pl-1 text-xs-right text-ellipsis hide-on-open" fxShow="false" fxShow.gt-sm>
                  <small class="text-muted">Tarih</small>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**.ts File**

```
onSelect(analysis: FormGroup): void {
  console.log("Analysis",this.analysisFormArray);
  console.log("Select Analysis",analysis);
    this.selectedAnalysis = analysis;
   
}
```

[image]

[image]

I'm having trouble with reactive form in Angular 12
While the form array in the selected form group should be full, it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

use index:

```
onSelect(index: number): void {
 this.selectedAnalysisIndex = index;
}
```

then:

```
[class.selected]="index === selectedAnalysisIndex"
```

Comment: No, the problem is that the array in the selected object is empty, normally the array is full